# How to create multiple admin users for kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to set up a kubernetes cluster that supports [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) and have multiple admin users. If I create an user like [this](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/), I end up creating ordinary user where I need to specify individual capabilities using the ROLES config file. Instead, how do I create multiple users having admin privileges?

Comment: Are you looking to create a cluster admin for one namespace or cluster wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an easier way to do it. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/10/using-rbac-generally-available-18/

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
--user=user1 --user=user2 --group=group1
```